# Jquery and $(document).ready(function()

Tags: jquery, document, ready, devil

I've read many things about $(document).ready(function()
it's clear when it is usefull ,
so generally i write $(document).ready(function() inside

but , why the devil , why is it KO in this so simple case ?
if you just put off le $(doc.... it works perfectly

code :

```
<?php
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script defer>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //alert('ready boy');
            function changeText(id) {
                id.innerHTML = "Ooops!";
            }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<h1 onclick="changeText(this)">Click on this text!</h1>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `changeText` is not accessible from outside of `ready()`. So, it will not work. Use `on('click')` to bind event.

Comment: You do not need to put methods inside of a document ready wrapper.

Comment: Not an ideal duplicate, but the answer is the same, functions are only available in their scope (in this case inside the the doc ready).

Answer (score 1):

First, I would advice against using inline JavaScript as it may be difficult to maintain the code. Thus you would not need a named function.

Secondly, the named function is not accessible globally, which is where the inline code is looking for it.

Here is a demo showing how you could approach this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //alert('ready boy');
    $('h1.changeit').on('click', function() {
        $(this).text('Ooops!'); //.html('Ooops!')
        //OR this.innerHTML = "Ooops!";
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="changeit">Click on this text!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a scope problem. When using the outdated `on*` event attributes the function you call must be defined under the scope of the `window`. In your code example you've defined it within the scope of jQuery's ready handler.

To fix this you can either move the function to be directly within the `<script>` tag, and hence under the `window` scope:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script defer>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('ready boy');
    });

    function changeText(id) {
      id.innerHTML = "Ooops!";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 onclick="changeText(this)">Click on this text!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, and preferably, you could remove the `on*` event attribute and attach your event handler using unobtrusive Javascript instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script defer>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      console.log('ready boy');

      $('h1').click(function() {
        this.innerHTML = "Ooops!";
        // $(this).text('Ooops!'); // alternative
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Click on this text!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```